# PHP: How to get unique content from array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a array and I need unique contents. How can I get rid of duplicates in this **$tmparray**:

```
array(176) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(22) "/ads/67006/didi"
    [1]=>
    string(73) "/Content/Pictures/Scaled/7b5c69572fdb1569ced695c278072ae0.jpg"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(22) "/ads/67006/didi"
    [1]=>
    string(73) "/Content/Pictures/Scaled/7b5c69572fdb1569ced695c278072ae0.jpg"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(22) "/ads/67006/didi"
    [1]=>
    string(73) "/Content/Pictures/Scaled/7b5c69572fdb1569ced695c278072ae0.jpg"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(19) "/ads/67010/sylvesta"
    [1]=>
    string(73) "/Content/Pictures/Scaled/83ebba04b8eabd0458cc6dbbb85581da.jpg"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(19) "/ads/67010/sylvesta"
    [1]=>
    string(73) "/Content/Pictures/Scaled/83ebba04b8eabd0458cc6dbbb85581da.jpg"
  }
  [5]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(19) "/ads/67010/sylvesta"
    [1]=>
    string(73) "/Content/Pictures/Scaled/83ebba04b8eabd0458cc6dbbb85581da.jpg"
  }
```

But I want it to look like: (Only unique contents.)

```
array(176) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(22) "/ads/67006/didi"
    [1]=>
    string(73) "/Content/Pictures/Scaled/7b5c69572fdb1569ced695c278072ae0.jpg"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(19) "/ads/67010/sylvesta"
    [1]=>
    string(73) "/Content/Pictures/Scaled/83ebba04b8eabd0458cc6dbbb85581da.jpg"
  }
  }
```

I have tried with:

```
array_unique($tmparray);
```

array_unique can't do what I want. Anyone have a idea how to solve this?

Comment: are you adding this data to the "$tmparray" ?

Comment: @AbdullahMallik this is result from var_dump($tmparray) now I need to remove duplicated contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working with this line:

```
$tmparray = array_unique($tmparray, SORT_REGULAR);
```

Answer (score 2):

your question seems duplicate of this
[How to remove duplicate values from a multi-dimensional array in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307674/how-to-remove-duplicate-values-from-a-multi-dimensional-array-in-php)

i guess array_map will solve your problem

```
$input = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $input)));
```

Comment: Thank you, this really works. But I found an other solution in the Link you provided which is shorter and works as I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
$newarray= array();
foreach ($tmparray as $value) {
    if (!in_array($value,$newarray)) {
        $newarray[ ] = $value;
    }
}
var_dump($newarray);
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that by duplicate you mean two items where either elements are matching, since you are mapping ads to their pictures, therefore:

```
$target = array();
$elementCount = count($tmparray);
$newElementCount = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i < $elementCount; $i++) {
    $found = false;
    for ($j = 0; (!$found) && (j < $newElementCount); j++) {
        $found = $target[$j][0] === $tmparray[$i][0] || $target[$j][1] === $tmparray[$i][1];
    }
    if (!$found) {
        $target[$newElementCount++]=$tmparray[$i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP `array_unique` is used only for single dimensional arrays, for multidimensional you can do this by serializing multidimensional array, like below

```
<?php 
$dataArray = [
                0=>["/ads/67006/didi","/Content/Pictures/Scaled/7b5c69572fdb1569ced695c278072ae0.jpg"],
                1=>["/ads/67010/sylvesta","/Content/Pictures/Scaled/83ebba04b8eabd0458cc6dbbb85581da.jpg"],
                2=>["/ads/67006/didi","/Content/Pictures/Scaled/7b5c69572fdb1569ced695c278072ae0.jpg"],
                3=>["/ads/67010/sylvesta","/Content/Pictures/Scaled/83ebba04b8eabd0458cc6dbbb85581da.jpg"],
             ];
$serilaized = [];
$newArr = [];
### serilaize each node of multi array and create a new single dimention array..         
foreach($dataArray as $val){
    $serilaized[] = serialize($val); 
}
### now perform array unique..
$serilaized_unique = array_unique($serilaized);
## unserialize each node of uniqur array..
foreach($serilaized_unique as $val){
    $newArr[] = unserialize($val);
}
echo "<pre>";print_r($newArr);
?>
```

This will give you:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => /ads/67006/didi
            [1] => /Content/Pictures/Scaled/7b5c69572fdb1569ced695c278072ae0.jpg
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => /ads/67010/sylvesta
            [1] => /Content/Pictures/Scaled/83ebba04b8eabd0458cc6dbbb85581da.jpg
        )

)
```

In short you can perform this in single line code with `array_map`

```
$dataArray = array_map('unserialize', array_unique(array_map('serialize', $dataArray)));
```